# I installed react but the browser does not open at all whenever I save it in visual studio code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, visual-studio-code

I am new to react js and I installed react I also have live server extension installed but anytime I save my work for the browser to automatically refresh ,the google chrome browser does not open at all please what’s the issue

Comment: Without seeing your configurations is hard to figure out what is happening. Did you use create-react-app? if not use it and it will be much easier to start https://create-react-app.dev/

Comment: Yes I did the exact installation